# Why does NotImplemented evaluate to True?

Tags: python

I recently stumbled upon Python's `NotImplemented` builtin. After some reading I do get it's purpose now, but I don't see why it evaluates to `True` as a boolean. The following example makes it seem like some kind of cruel joke to me:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return NotImplemented
... 
>>> 
>>> a = A()
>>> a == 1
False
>>> bool(a.__eq__(1))
True
```

My question is simple: Why does `NotImplemented` evaluate to `True`?

Comment: usually exception are supposed to be raised, not returned

Comment: @RuggeroTurra `NotImplemented` is of the type `NotImplementedType`, it's not an exception at all. There _is_ a `NotImplementedError`; in a case like this I'd probably replace `return NotImplemented` with `raise NotImplementedError`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because it doesn't evaluate to `False`; the *default* is to consider all objects `True` unless they have a [length of 0](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) (containers), or [are zero](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) (numeric); see the [Truth Value Testing reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

**However**, returning `NotImplemented` signals to Python that the equality test is not implemented, and the inverse `(1).__eq__(a)` is tried instead. If that method doesn't exist either, the objects are not equal if they are not the same object (`a is 1` is `False`).

In other words, `NotImplemented` is a special singleton object, a sentinel to signal to Python that you want Python to try something else, as the equality test between this object and the other is not supported.

As such it was never meant to be used in a boolean context. It is never meant to convey `False`.

Comment: Typo: Should be `the default is to consider all objects True unless it has a length 0 (containers), or it evaluates to 0 (numeric)` A numeric object with a non-zero value would be `True`

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Well I still think it is backwards the way it is written, no? Should be `...the default is to consider all objects True unless they are 1) the False or None objects; or 2) have a length of 0 (containers), or 3) evaluate to zero (numeric); or 4) define  __nonzero__.` If something numeric evaluates to nonzero, that is True.  `bool(.00001)`